# Where to enter verification code?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I have an iphone 8 and when I tap on my accountinfo in settings (where it has my name and says apple ID, cloud, itunes and more) and I get to the menu where it says "password & security" -- I tap on that and it asks if i want a verification code, the only other option is "OK". I tap "OK" and nothing happens. I tap get a code and it sends a code to my phone but where the heck do I enter it? Nothing comes up on my computer when i do this. Please HELP! This is an amazingly annoying thing about iOS today. I can't seem to find anything like this in similar questions.

To clarify: I see no menu, no response on my computer and I am at a loss where to tap in the numbers the iphone is showing me.

Comment: Apple support might be needed if you can’t get more details on how you have set up your account and what specific device has which specific items visible or running.

Comment: Iphone 8. I just powered it on. At the bottom of the account screen the little turning thing won't stop. I am not sure what you mean by "how I set up my account" -- it has 2fac on and at least sometimes it will tell me that I am signing in on a new device.

Comment: Apple has two step, two factor, sms, push, Mac, iOS options so you might need to enter approval on a Mac based on how you set things up. It could take 20 questions to narrow down how your approval flow should work and where it might be hung up if it’s not just reviewing with you the choices made to confirm a legitimate log in